# How to remove non-alphanumerics in python

Tags: python

For this function, my code only works for this example, but I don't know why it doesn't work for all examples. Can anyone help me?

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return s with all non-space or non-alphanumeric
    characters removed.
    >>> remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')
    'a b c 3'
    '''
    new_str = ''
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha():
            new_str = new_str + char + " "
    new_s = new_str[:len(new_str)-1]
    return new_s
```

here is what I have.

Comment: How do I make this function work for all examples and cases?

Comment: It might be helpful to post an example where it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to this line

```
new_str = new_str + char + " "
```

your code always adds a space after each preserved character. Thus runs of alphanumeric characters end up with spaces in between.

Another example where your function does not work is when there are multiple spaces within a string, e.g. `'a,    b, c, 3!!  '`. According to your description the spaces should be preserved.

Your function can also check whether a character is a space using `isspace()`. This will include the space character, as well as tabs, new lines etc. :

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return s with all non-space or non-alphanumeric
    characters removed.
    >>> remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')
    'a b c 3'
    '''
    new_str = ''
    for char in s:
        if char.isalnum() or char.isspace():
            new_str = new_str + char
    return new_str

print(repr(remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')))
print(repr(remove_punctuation('a,    b, c, 3!!')))
```

Output:

```
'a b c 3'
'a    b c 3'
```

If you only want to preserve space characters then you can replace `char.isspace()` with `char == ' '`.

---

Here is a common way to remove the characters from a string using [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a list comprehension/generator expression:

```
def remove_punctuation(s):
    '''(str) -> str
    Return s with all non-space or non-alphanumeric
    characters removed.
    >>> remove_punctuation('a, b, c, 3!!')
    'a b c 3'
    '''
    return ''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum() or c.isspace())
```